# scrambled arabic in Telerik reports

Tags: unicode, telerik, report, arabic

I have issue in Arabic language in telerik report ... I have text boxes that contains static Arabic strings and database data that bind to a table in the same report. the static strings are scrambled but the table shows correct text, and both have the same font.
I did tried changing font and installing  Arial Unicode font but still having the same error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DW5QI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Set the localization property of the report to true

[image]